# Using Razor to call C# function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple piece of HTML code which is supposed to call C# function on a press of a button, but it looks like the URL is bad, can anyone help me with Razor syntax? So far I have the following:

```
<div class="test1">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h1>Some button</h1>
    <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("addAdress", "AdressController")'" />
    <p></p>
</div>
```

And here is the Controller that is supposed to do something, name of the Controller is AdressController

```
private void addAdress()
    {
        Adress a = new Adress();

        a.Number = "1";
        a.Distance = 100;

        Dictionary<string, object> queryDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        queryDict.Add("Number", a.Number);
        queryDict.Add("Distance", a.Distance);

        var query = new Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherQuery("CREATE (n:Adress {Number:'" + a.Number + "', Distance:'" + a.Distance + "'}) return n",
                                                        queryDict, CypherResultMode.Set);

        List<Adress> adrese = ((IRawGraphClient)client).ExecuteGetCypherResults<Adress>(query).ToList();

        /*
        foreach (Adress a1 in adrese)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(a1.Number);
        }
        */
    }
```

Comment: Try this : <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("addAdress", "Adress")'" />

Comment: You showed us your "controller method" but it's not an action method. Seems like you need to [review the basics of MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/). You should return an ActionResult, your method should be public, and you should have routing configured for it.

Comment: well href will expect a url if you don't want that then use preventDefault() and cont. with your operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller Method is `private`, try changing to `public`

***Sugestion***

If you are going to change `location.href` on click, just wrap the input inside a link:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("addAdress", "Adress")'>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me">
</a>
```

Comment: It also needs to be `"Address"` not `"AddressController"`

Comment: Yes, that was the solution I needed, much appreciated