# Running a C# function on an onclick to modify SVG file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, svg

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application with a couple of coded in functions in the .cshtml pages(Razor). This one in particular I'd like to run when an a-tag gets clicked on. This code will essential will go to a locally stored .svg file and change some of the styling attributes. The code for that is below, and *is stored in the View*.

```
public static void turnRed()
{   
    var pathToSVG = "path/to/svg";
    var doc = XDocument.Load(pathToSVG);
    var node = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("rect", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")).FirstOrDefault(cd => cd.Attribute("id").Value == "rect1");

    node.SetAttributeValue("fill", "red");

    doc.Save(pathToSVG);
}
```

Now in the actual html I would like to have a simple onclick expression that would run the code when the a-tag gets pressed.

```
    <a onclick="@{ turnRed(); }" href="#">Change SVG color</a>
```

What I have right now for whatever reason gets called onload, and not on click. How might I go about this? If there's a way to to do it without JavaScript, that would be ideal, but whatever works. Thanks!

Here are some of the concepts I've looked at and tried already:

[Using Razor to call C# function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995423/using-razor-to-call-c-sharp-function)

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-create-razor-function-in-asp-net-mvc-view1

https://asp.mvc-tutorial.com/razor/local-functions/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor page allows the use of `handler methods`. To call a method from your page you need to put `On` + the http verb + your method name. In my tests this didn't work with static methods

Change your signature method for:

> public void OnGetTurnRed()

And change your 'a' for:

```html
<a asp-page-handler="TurnRed">Change SVG color</a>
```

[Docs Razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2)